# Delete rows one row above certain text and stop at blank row above

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all the rows highlighted in the image, *The actual document doesn't have those areas highlighted.*

[image]

I need a macros to:

1. Find the text Sub
2. Delete everything one row above the row with the word Sub
3. Stop at the blank row above
4. Loop the whole document

Comment: You'll need to make an effort to do this on your own. We generally don't write code for you, but rather help you address specific problems you're running into. To get started, you'll want to take a look at the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx). If you get stuck, edit your question to include what code you've tried.

Comment: Pseudo Code: 1. loop from bottom row 2. delete row whenever above row is the same.

Comment: Are you looking to delete the entire row or just the data in the cells?

Comment: Trying to delete the entire row. I was going to put the code on here but it was so unclear and didn't do what I wanted that I didn't want to confuse anyone. I'm really new at this so sorry, guys.  Thanks for your help though, I really appreciate it! : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim mySht As Worksheet
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim nRows As Long, iCount As Long

    Set mySht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set myRng = mySht.UsedRange

    nRows = myRng.Rows.Count

    iCount = nRows
    Do While iCount > 0
        If myRng.Cells(iCount, 3).Value = "SUB" Then
            If myRng.Cells(iCount - 2, 3).Value <> "" Then
                myRng.Rows(iCount - 2).Delete (xlShiftUp)
                Set myRng = myRng.Resize(myRng.Rows.Count - 1, myRng.Columns.Count)
            End If
        End If
        iCount = iCount - 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Sheet1 starts out like this ...

[image]

and ends up like this ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked like a charm! But some of the data below didn't get sorted out for some reason. Also, how do I make this available for all active work sheets? I tried to change the Set mySht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") to Set mySht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveSheet") but didn't work.

Comment: Instead of a string (e.g. `"Sheet1"`), you can set up a loop (e.g. `for Each mySht in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`). In this case you would remove the `Set` line, because the loop is doing it for you.

Comment: So instead of Set mySht=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("s") it'll be

Comment: Replace `Set mySht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` with `For Each mySht in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`. Then, after `Loop` but before `End Sub` insert the line `Next mySht`. This will cycle through all of the sheets in your workbook.

Comment: And, if this answered your question, you should click the check mark next to it. Thanks.

Comment: ,I have tried the following and there was an error. I have tried to add the images to your post above. Hopefully you can see it. It’s showing up as a link by your *Try this* Description.

Comment: This part of the code `If myRng.Cells(iCount - 2, 3).Value <> "" Then` checks the third column (Column C) for a blank - if it's blank then it assumes it has reached the end of items that need to be removed. If you have data with blanks in column C, then you will need to change it to look in column A or B. Change the `3` to `1` or `2`.

Comment: Notice in my comment about adding a loop, the syntax is `For Each mySht in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` there is NO `Set` - if you preface this statement with `Set` VBA will not compile.

Comment: Sorry, I re-read your comment about looping and I'm still not sure what you mean. What should the line there show? Should it be written out like this? (Set mySht = For Each mySht in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets there is NO Set) Minus the brackets? Sorry, I'm so new at this.

Comment: I figured it out! I changed Dim mysht as worksheet. Thanks so much!